# android studio - camera freezes after a second

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-camera, freeze

The camera seems to start for about 1-2 seconds, and then just freezes and the emulator shuts down. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. This is API 23 Marshmallow.

I have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

on my AndroidManifest.xml.

```
    takePhotoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ProfileCreationActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Camera_Photo");
                if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
                    mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
                }
                File mediaFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Camera_Photo");
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mediaFile));
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAM_REQUEST);

            } else {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{ Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_CAM_REQUEST);
            }

        }
    });


    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (requestCode == CAM_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String filename = "IMG_test1.jpg";
            photoIV.setImageURI(file);

        }
    }

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of emulator try using any physical device

Comment: I did, same result :(